# Go to another ViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift

i have a ViewController where in the ViewDidLoad i call a method to evaluate TouchID policy.

I have made in storyboard a tab bar controller with 3 tabs. I want to go to the tab bar controller if touchID validation returns "ok".

Has anyone know how to do it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Hide the `tabbar` or disable tabs until `touchId` not authenticate or show another Authenticaton ViewController first and than make `tabbar rootViewController` after authentication alternatively you can present `AuthenticationViewController` on tabbarViewController and dismiss it after authentiction.

Comment: I have a first ViewController where i do the TouchID authentication, but i am not catching how to present the tabbar after the fingerprint validation.